# Can DDD repositories return data from other aggregate roots?

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, dao, data-access-layer, aggregateroot

I'm having trouble getting my head around how to use the repository pattern with a more complex object model. Say I have two aggregate roots `Student` and `Class`. Each student may be enrolled in any number of classes. Access to this data would therefore be through the respective repositories `StudentRepository` and `ClassRepository`.

[image]

Now on my front end say I want to create a student details page that shows the information about the student, and a list of classes they are enrolled in. I would first have to get the `Student` from `StudentRepository` and then their `Classes` from `ClassRepository`. This makes sense.

Where I get lost is when the domain model becomes more realistic/complex. Say students have a major that is associated with a department, and classes are associated with a course, room, and instructors. Rooms are associated with a building. Course are associated with a department etc.. etc..

[image]

I could easily see wanting to show information from all these entities on the student details page. But then I would have to make a number of calls to separate repositories per each class the student is enrolled in. So now what could have been a couple queries to the database has increased massively. This doesn't seem right.

I understand the `ClassRepository` should only be responsible for updating classes, and not anything in other aggregate roots. But does it violate DDD if the values `ClassRepository` returns contains information from other related aggregate roots? In most cases this would only need to be a partial summary of those related entities (building name, course name, course number, instructor name, instructor email etc..).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can DDD repositories return data from other aggregate roots?

Short answer: No. If that happened, that would not be a DDD repository for a DDD aggregate (that said, nobody will go after you if you do it).

Long answer: Your problem is that you are trying to use tools made to safely modify data (aggregates and repositories) to solve a problem reading data for presentation purposes. An aggregate is a consistency boundary. Its goal is to implement a process and encapsulate the data required for that process. The repository's goal is to read and atomically update a single aggregate. It is not meant to implement queries needed for data presentation to users.

Also, note that the model you present is not a model based on aggregates. If you break that model into aggregates you'll have multiple clusters of entities without "lines" between them. For example, a Student aggregate might have a collection of ClassEnrollments and a Class aggregate a collection of Atendees (that's just an example, note that modeling many to many relationships with aggregates can be a bit tricky). You'll have one repository for each aggregate, which will fully load the aggregate when executing an operation and transactionally update the full aggregate.

Now to your actual question: how do you implement queries for data presentation that require data from multiple aggregates? well, you have multiple options:

1. As you say, do multiple round trips using your existing repositories. Load a student and from the list of ClassEnrollments, load the classes that you need.
2. Use CQRS "lite". Aggregates and respositories will only be used for update operations and for query operations implement Queries, which won't use repositories, but access the DB directly, therefore you can join tables from multiple aggregates (Student->Enrollments->Atendees->Classes)
3. Use "full" CQRS. Create read models optimised for your queries based on the data from your aggregates.

My preferred approach is to use CQRS lite and only create a dedicated read model when it's really needed.

Answer (score 2):

> But then I would have to make a number of calls to separate repositories per each class the student is enrolled in. So now what could have been a couple queries to the database has increased massively. This doesn't seem right.

Yup.

> But does it violate DDD if the values ClassRepository returns contains information from other related aggregate roots?

Nobody cares about "violate DDD".  What we care about is: do you still get the benefits of the repository pattern if you start pulling in data from other aggregates?

Probably not - part of the point of "aggregates" is that when writing the business code you don't have to worry to much about how storage is implemented... but if you start mixing locked data and unlocked data, your abstraction starts leaking into the domain code.

However: if you are trying to support reporting, or some other effectively read only function, you don't necessarily need the domain model at all -- it might make sense to just query your data store and present a representation of the answer.

This substitution isn't necessarily "free" -- the accuracy of the information will depend in part on how closely your stored information matches your in memory information (ie, how often are you writing information into your storage).

This is basically the core idea of CQRS: reads and writes are different, so maybe we should separate the two, so that they each can be optimized without interfering with the correctness of the other.